# How can I have multiple blockquotes back to back?

Tags: support, spoilers

Let's say I want to quote two different sections of the same page.  So I try to put two separate blockquotes back to back, but this doesn't work:

Code:

```
> We could cause a diplomatic crisis. Take the ship into the Neutral Zone And blowing into maximum warp speed, you appeared for an instant to be in two places at once.

> Wouldn't that bring about chaos? I'll be sure to note that in my log.
```

Result:

> We could cause a diplomatic crisis. Take the ship into the Neutral Zone And blowing into maximum warp speed, you appeared for an instant to be in two places at once.
>
> Wouldn't that bring about chaos? I'll be sure to note that in my log.

Instead you get one long blockquote, which makes it look like its one long quote.  How can you get two separate back to back blockquotes?

<sub>Text provided by [Riker Ipsum](http://www.rikeripsum.com/#!/)</sub>

Comment: Ah! I've wondered this too! Thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 9):

Add a `<!-- break>` between the two blocks, and you'll get two separate blockquotes.  The `<!-- (stuff)>` is an HTML comment, which web browsers don't display.

Code:

```
> Fear is the true enemy, the only enemy. Why don't we just give everybody a promotion and call it a night - 'Commander'? 

<!-- break>

> Then maybe you should consider this: if anything happens to them, Starfleet is going to want a full investigation.
```

Result:

> Fear is the true enemy, the only enemy. Why don't we just give everybody a promotion and call it a night - 'Commander'?

> Then maybe you should consider this: if anything happens to them, Starfleet is going to want a full investigation.

This also works for spoiler blocks:

> And blowing into maximum warp speed, you appeared for an instant to be in two places at once. A surprise party? Mr. Worf, I hate surprise parties.

> I would *never* do that to you. When has justice ever been as simple as a rule book?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you'd want to put an attribution before each quote or before each quote.

> To be or not to be, that is the question.

(William Shakespeare)

> I don't know.

(Arthur Dent)

---

If you want to cite two snippets from the same work, put them in a single blockquote with an ellipsis to indicate where you interrupted the citation.

> By and large, the only skill the alchemists of Ankh-Morpork had discovered so far was the ability to turn gold into less gold.
>
> (…)
>
> Most alchemists were nervous, in any case; it came from not knowing what the crucible of bubbling stuff they were experimenting with was going to do next.

---

If you really find a use for two blockquotes next to each other, put some empty markup in between. An [HTML](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#html) comment, for example.

```
> Hello.

<!-- -->
> Hello again.
```

> Hello.

> Hello again.